# Angular timing/binding problems in getting data from REST service and showing them in the DOM

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I seem to have some difficulties with Angular http calls, and using the data retrieved in a meaningful way.

What I am trying to do is to create a carousel, but the images come from our REST services. I can set up the carousel just fine, if I use a local json-array to fill it, but the data I'm retrieving from our REST api arrives too late to be included in the DOM, and I'm not getting it in there.

I'm using Angular 1.5 and the [ui.carousel](https://github.com/mihnsen/ui-carousel) plugin. In this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/LUuPSUl34oNFubBrzXpz?p=preview) I've recreated what I have locally, and you can see that the first few panda images are being loaded from the defined json, but the http.get() data that I overwrote the $scope.slides variable with, does not display. It seems like there is *some* communication *somewhere*, as the pagination-dots do update, and the slider keeps on sliding, but if you look in the DOM, there are no more slides after the first (10? when I've defined 5?, probably a ui.carousel feature?)

Html:

```
<ui-carousel slides="slides" slides-to-show="3" slides-to-scroll="3" initial-slide="0" autoplay="true" autoplay-speed="2000" dots="true">
    <carousel-item>
      <img src="{{ item.url }}" width="200px">
    </carousel-item>
</ui-carousel>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.carousel']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$http', '$scope',
    function($http, $scope) {

        $scope.slides = [{"id":1,"url":"http://i.imgur.com/yTrf6sJ.jpg"},
            {"id":2,"url":"http://i.imgur.com/yTrf6sJ.jpg"},
            {"id":3,"url":"http://i.imgur.com/yTrf6sJ.jpg"},
            {"id":4,"url":"http://i.imgur.com/yTrf6sJ.jpg"},
            {"id":5,"url":"http://i.imgur.com/yTrf6sJ.jpg"}];

        $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1/photos').then(function(response) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
            $scope.slides = response.data;
        });
    }
]);
```

Remote RESTservice JSON:

```
[
    {
        "albumId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt",
        "url": "http://placehold.it/600/92c952",
        "thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/92c952"
    },
    {
        "albumId": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "title": "reprehenderit est deserunt velit ipsam",
        "url": "http://placehold.it/600/771796",
        "thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/771796"
    }, etc.
```

It seems to me that the $scope.slides referenced in the DOM does not get updated after the http call, even though the array itself does get updated with the new data. The DOM seems to hold on to the old data.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think its because you are overwriting the array $scope.slides. Instead try to push it if you want to append anything to the array
$scope.slides.push(response.data);

Comment: there is already a bug post [see this](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/488)

Comment: @CrazyMac, this doesn't change the result, sadly: https://plnkr.co/edit/LUuPSUl34oNFubBrzXpz?p=preview I just get an empty variable.

Comment: @AnuragDadheech, shouldn't it be fixed then according to kkruit's commit on 11th of November '14? (https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/488#ref-commit-bfa58c0)

Comment: @Kablam Change your iteration as below, I have updated your plnkr
    $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1/photos').then(function(response) {
      angular.forEach(response.data, function(element, index){
        $scope.slides.push(element);  
      })

https://plnkr.co/edit/QfpujG5wubXvbGO4Lofd?p=preview

Comment: Ah, yes thanks. Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the non-updating array though...

Answer (score -2):

I have updated your plnkr. Please check the URL. The way you iterate and push it to the array has been changed

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$http', '$scope',
function($http, $scope) {

$scope.slides = [
{"id":1,"url":"http://i.imgur.com/yTrf6sJ.jpg"},
    {"id":2,"url":"http://i.imgur.com/yTrf6sJ.jpg"},
    {"id":3,"url":"http://i.imgur.com/yTrf6sJ.jpg"},
    {"id":4,"url":"http://i.imgur.com/yTrf6sJ.jpg"},
    {"id":5,"url":"http://i.imgur.com/yTrf6sJ.jpg"}];
$http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1/photos').then(function(response) {
    angular.forEach(response.data, function(element, index){
        $scope.slides.push(element.url);  
    })

 });
```

}
]);

Refer the image for more details. I dumped the slides in the HTML and it displays all the element

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but... does it work for you? Doe you see more images than just the panda's I'm locally loading? 'Cause as far as I can see, this doesn't fix my issues :(

Comment: Yes I could see other images.. Its a big list

Comment: I think the array looks fine to me. It is just that check how the directive you are using will render the updated array

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I honestly only see the first few images of the pandas that were loaded before I queried the REST service. -> http://i.imgur.com/NaQct47.png. I am looking at your plunker and I edited mine to include your changes as well, but no new images, not in the view nor in the DOM.

Comment: Please look at the image I have attached. I am not sure about the directive that you are using for the carousel but you can check {{slides}} is displaying all the items and the url

Comment: You see, the actual problem isn't that the array isn't filled. It is perfectly filled, even with my original method of just replacing the arrays content completely instead of pushing the items. The issue is that the view does not update. I've edited the question to make this more clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142496/discussion-between-crazymac-and-kablam).

Comment: @Kablam The directive you are using could be the problem. Which version    and can you post the URL of the same